# expected value of joint density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be jointly continuous random variables with joint density:$$f_{\small X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{3}(x+y)&,& {\text{for} \space x\in(0,1) \space \text{and} \space y\in(0,2)} \\[1ex] 0&,& \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$
>
> Compute $\mathbb{E}[\sin(\pi XY)]$.

If we define $Z=g_{\small X,Y}(x,y)=\sin(\pi XY)$, then
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z] = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\, g_{\small X,Y}(x,y)\,f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy
$$
I am unsure of how to compute this due to the $\sin$ function. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a standard integration by parts. Can you compute $\int x sin(x) dx$?

Comment: as long as you know integral of $\sin x$ and of $x \sin x$, you should be able to do it.

Comment: @A.Pesare yes I can, but what about $y$?

Comment: @A.Pesare Also, would the limits remain as x between 0 and 1 and y as between 0 and 2?

Comment: Have you ever computed double integrals? You first consider $y$ as a fixed number and integrate with respect to $x$ only and then integrate with respect to $y$ (or viceversa).

For the second question: yes!

Answer (score 1):

To get you started:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E[\sin(XY\pi)]&=\iint_{\Bbb R^2}\sin(xy\pi)\,f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d\langle x,y\rangle \\[1ex]&=\frac 13\iint_{(0,1)\times(0,2)} (x+y)\sin(xy\pi)~\mathrm d\langle x, y\rangle\\[1ex] & = \frac13\left(\int_0^1x \int_0^2\sin(xy\pi)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x+\int_0^2y \int_0^1\sin(xy\pi)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\right)\\&~~\vdots\end{align}$$